# numpy implementing a custom RNG

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

I'm trying to get numpy to use my own implementation of an RNG in for consistency reasons. My understanding, based on the little documentation I could find, from the numpy docs [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/bit_generators/generated/numpy.random.BitGenerator.html#numpy.random.BitGenerator) and [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html) is that I need to provide a custom BitGenerator class that implements the `random_raw` method and then initialise using `np.random.Generator`, so I tried this:

```
import numpy as np

class TestBitGenerator(np.random.BitGenerator):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(0)
    self.counter = 0
  def random_raw(self, size=None):
    self.counter += 1
    if size is None:
      return self.counter
    return np.full(n, self.counter)  

mc_adapter = TestBitGenerator() 
npgen = np.random.Generator(mc_adapter)

print(npgen.random())
```

which results in a segfault:

```
$ python bitgen.py 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I assume I'm missing something (from TestBitGenerator?) here, can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried not subclassing np.random.BitGenerator, and got a different error:
`object has no attribute 'capsule'`

I using numpy 1.19.2 and python 3.8.2

Comment: If it is for consistency reasons, why don't you just set the seed to a consistent value?

Comment: It didn't seem relevant to the question to explain my exact needs as its complicated. I have some C++ code (including my RNG) taking to python via pybind11, and I'm running on MPI and I need control over how each process is seeded, and each process should (ideally) use just a single random stream accessible from both the C++ and python layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/_generator.pyx) and `Generator`'s constructor looks like this:

```
    def __init__(self, bit_generator):
        self._bit_generator = bit_generator

        capsule = bit_generator.capsule
        cdef const char *name = "BitGenerator"
        if not PyCapsule_IsValid(capsule, name):
            raise ValueError("Invalid bit generator. The bit generator must "
                             "be instantiated.")
        self._bitgen = (<bitgen_t *> PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, name))[0]
        self.lock = bit_generator.lock
```

also [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/c-api.html) explains the requirements for the `bitgen_t` struct:

```
struct bitgen:
    void *state
    npy_uint64 (*next_uint64)(void *st) nogil
    uint32_t (*next_uint32)(void *st) nogil
    double (*next_double)(void *st) nogil
    npy_uint64 (*next_raw)(void *st) nogil

ctypedef bitgen bitgen_t
```

so from what I can make out, it looks like any implementation of `BitGenerator` must be done in cython, any attempt to implement one in pure python (and probably pybind11 too) just won't work(?)

As I'm not familiar with cython and if/how it could coexist with pybind11, for now I'm just going to ensure each of my (parallel) processes explicitly calls np.random.Generator with a numpy RNG seeded deterministically so that it's independent from my own RNG steam.

Comment: If you found a limitation in `numpy.random.Generator` that you care about, you may want to file an issue on that: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues .  Also, an example showing how multithreaded random generation works is in the NumPy documentation, in case you didn't see it: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/multithreading.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can do it in pure python if you wrap it using the library `RandomGen` (this was the incubator for the current `np.random.Generator`). So there is a `UserBitGenerator` that allow you to use only python: https://bashtage.github.io/randomgen/bit_generators/userbitgenerator.html

Sad that this did not make it in `numpy` (or if it is I did not find it yet...).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using pybind11, it's not too hard, although there's no good documentation explaining any of this, so it took me a while to figure it out.  Here is what I came up with, so hopefully this will save a few people some consternation.

1. Define your custom bit generator in C++.  You'll need to define three functions: `next_unint32`, `next_uint64`, and `next_double`, each returning the next random value of the given type.  (Typically one of these will be primary, and you'll define the other two based on it.)  They all need to take one argument, given as `void*`, which you'll want to recast to whatever you actually have for a state object.  Say a pointer to an instance of some class `CustomRNG` or whatever.
2. Write a function that takes a pointer to your state object and a `py::capsule` (I use `namespace py = pybind11`, so spell that out if you don't do this.)  This capsule wraps a `bitgen_t` struct, and writes the appropriate values to its elements.  Something like the following:

```
#include <numpy/random/bitgen.h>  // For bitgen_t struct

// For reference:
/*
typedef struct bitgen {
  void *state;
  uint64_t (*next_uint64)(void *st);
  uint32_t (*next_uint32)(void *st);
  double (*next_double)(void *st);
  uint64_t (*next_raw)(void *st);
} bitgen_t;
*/

void SetupBitGen(CustomRNG* rng, py::capsule capsule)
{
    bitgen_t* bg(capsule);
    bg->state = rng;
    bg->next_uint64 = next_uint64;
    bg->next_uint32 = next_uint32;
    bg->next_double = next_double;
    bg->next_raw = next_uint64;
};
```

3. Have pybind11 wrap this for you so you can call it from python.  I'm also assuming that your `CustomRNG` type is already wrapped and accessible in python.

```
my_module.def("setup_bitgen", &SetupBitGen)
```

Or you could make this function a method of your `CustomRNG` class:

```
py::class_<CustomRNG>
    [...]
    .def("setup_bitgen", &SetupBitGen);
```

4. In Python make a class derived from `numpy.random.BitGenerator`, which takes an instance of your CustomRNG as an argument.  For the `__init__`, first call `super().__init__()` to make the things numpy expects to be there.  Then call `lib.setup_bitgen(self.rng, self.capsule)` (or `self.rng.setup_bitgen(self.capsule)` if you went the method route) to update the elements of the capsule.

That's it.  Now you can make your own BitGenerator object using this class, and pass that as an argument of `numpy.random.Generator`.

This is the method I used in GalSim, so you can see a worked example of it [here](https://github.com/GalSim-developers/GalSim/pull/1179).

Comment: Many thanks for this, I've now implemented something close you you example myself and it works. My only concern is that we have to roll our own `bitgen_t` struct to match numpy's;  and if they change it at some point in the future it will break badly (e.g. segfault) and it almost certainly will be far from obvious what the problem is.

Comment: @virgesmith FWIW, it's located in numpy/core/include/numpy/random/bitgen.h in the installed numpy repo.  So if you want to be a bit safer, you could add this directory to the C_INCLUDE_PATH programmatically in setup.py, and #include that.

Comment: I decided that was a good idea, so I did that in GalSim.  cf. https://github.com/GalSim-developers/GalSim/pull/1179/commits/586e8df791e4891ad233ee39c83c3ef27a2334e6

Comment: Definitely a good idea, have done likewise. Thanks again